# How to tell if two vectors span the same space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assume we have two vectors with five components.

Namely, $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5)$ and $u = (u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4, u_5)$.

I know that if they are linearly independent, the space that they span has dimension $2$ and I know that these vectors are not unique for that space (can be spanned by some other two vectors).

Question is, how can we tell if given another two vectors spans the same space?

Say, $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)$ and $y = (y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5)$.

Are linear combinations of $u$ and $v$ equal to linear combinations of $x$ and $y$? How can we answer such a question for the given vectors?

In other words, can we find a $(c, d)$ for every $(a, b)$ such that $au + bv = cx + dy$?

Comment: If $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ are also linearly independent, they span the same space if they are in $\mbox{span}\{ \vec u, \vec v\}$; i.e. if they can both be written as a linear combination of $\vec u$ and $\vec v$.

Comment: Mathematical formulae look better in $\LaTeX$. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) is a quick tutorial.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ have the same span if and only if the following ten questions all have answer yes: Is $u_1$ in the span of $v$? Is $u_2$ in the span of $v$? ... Is $u_5$ in the span of $v$? Is $v_1$ in the span of $u$? Is $v_2$ in the span of $u$? ... Is $v_5$ in the span of $u$? Each question is answered by setting up a certain linear equation, using the coefficients of the given vector, and seeing if that equation has a solution.

Comment: Notice that if $u=c_1x+d_1y$ and $v=c_2x+d_2y$ then $au+bv=(ac_1+bc_2)x+(ad_1+bd_2)y$. Thus, $c=ac_1+bc_2$ and $d=ad_1+bd_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x,y \in span(v,u)$ and if $x,y$ are linearly independent in $span(v,u)$ then $span(v,u)=span(x,y)$. This is due to the fact that if x and y are in the span of v and u then the span of x and y must be in it. Since they are both linearly independent this implies that $dim span(x,y) = dim span (u,v) $ implying that x,y is a basis of $span(u,v)$.